# How can I pass parent's column value as parameter to child report in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created master/details report from SSRS. Is it possible to pass as a parameter from parent's column value to child report. For e.g.

If I have a master report A and detail report B. From the following picture, how can I pass value of col_1 of Master_Report_A as a parameter for Details_Report_A[image]

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: If it is always going to be Master_Report_A's col_1 value, you can setup a hidden parameter to get the value from a dataset. Then use that parameter to send into the sub report.

Comment: Thank you avgbody. Can you elaborate more?